# Cannot select the dropdown with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to webscrap some data from a website and for that I have to go through the age verification using selenium. I was wondering if there is way to change the store location in the popup. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests as r


import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url1="https://cannacabana.com/collections/all?page=1"

driver.get(url1)

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#store-select")))).select_by_visible_text('ajax')
```

if someone can help I would really appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select the store location.
It is a `Select` element there.
There is a special way to use such element with selenium.
You can select an option from the list of available options according to displayed text, index or value as described in the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/select_lists/)
So your code could be something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests as r


import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url1="https://cannacabana.com/collections/all?page=1"

driver.get(url1)

select_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#store-select")))
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_value('rideau')
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems not to be working, I am getting below error, seems like by_value is not able to look for the "rideau", I am getting errorTimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: `errorTimeoutException` is caused by ` WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#store-select")))`. Please try using `presence_of_element_located` instead of `visibility_of_element_located` here. Let me know if now if working

Comment: It is showing me NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: rideau, I also tried changing the value from other stores and still the same issue

Comment: So, now instead of `errorTimeoutException` you are getting this `NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: rideau` Right?

Comment: Correct! That's the error I am getting, I there a way i can contact you besides here?

Comment: Okay, I wrote to you. Thanks!